# get all <li> of <ul> selenium python3

Tags: html, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-3.8

I have an html like this:

```
<ul class="page">
   <li id="p1"></li>
   <li id="p2"></li>
   <li id="p3"></li>
</ul>
```

I tried to find all the < li >s under that < ul > with the following code using selenium `Webdriver` in python:

```
my_ul = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@class='page']")
all_li = my_ul.find_element_by_tag_name("li")
    for li in all_li:
        print(li.text)
```

but when I ru it I got an Error:

```
>       for li in all_li:
E       TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable
```

can anybody explain to me what's wrong??

many thanks!

Comment: Try `for li in all_li.items(): `

Comment: that didn't work ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find_element_by_tag_name` returns a single element, you need to fetch the list to iterate over it. For that you need to use `find_elements_by_tag_name`.
Your code should be like:

```
my_ul = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@class='page']")
all_li = my_ul.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
    for li in all_li:
        print(li.text)
```

Comment: Ho yes! I just forgot that "s"!!! thank you very much @Sameer Arora